# passport-oauth2 client how to use profile data received

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I have a stand alone oauth2 identity provider that is working.
Now I'm developing a consumer that will authenticate users with this stand alone provider.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-quick-introduction-to-oauth-using-passport-js-65ea5b621a) about passport and Google Auth:

I'm trying to use this information to use passport-oauth2 to work as a client. I have made some changes in the code provided in the tutorial above by following the [official documentation on passoprt-oauth2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-oauth2).

I think that I have some problem in the callback function where expressjs receive the confirmation of authentication and info about the user. I don't understand how to use this information.

Here is the code of my app.js

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const passport = require('passport');
const OAuth2Strategy = require('passport-oauth2');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');

// cookieSession config
app.use(cookieSession({
    maxAge:24*60*60*1000,
    keys: ['secret-personalize']
}));


app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Strategy config


passport.use(new OAuth2Strategy({
    authorizationURL: 'http://localhost:3000/dialog/authorize',
    tokenURL: 'http://localhost:3000/oauth/token',
    clientID: 'xyz123',
    clientSecret: 'ssh-password',
    callbackURL: "/auth/oauth2/callback"
  },

  (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    console.log(profile);
    done(null, profile);

  }
  ));
  // Used to decode the received cookie and persist session

  passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);

  });

// Middleware to check if the User is authenticated

app.get('/auth/oauth2',
  passport.authenticate('oauth2'));


function isUserAuthenticated(req, res, next){

    if (req.user){
        next();
    } else {
        res.send('you must login!');
    }
}



// Routes

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

res.render('index.ejs');
});


// The middleware receives the data from AuthPRovider and runs the function on Strategy config

app.get('/auth/oauth2/callback', passport.authenticate('oauth2'), (req,res) => {
    res.redirect('/secret');
});



// secret route

app.get('/secret', isUserAuthenticated, (req, res) =>{

    res.send('You have reached the secret route');

});


// Logout route

app.get('/logout',(req, res) => {

    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');

});

    app.listen(8000, () => {
        console.log('Server Started 8000');
    });
```

and this is for views/index.ejs

```
 <ul>
    <li><a href="/auth/oauth2">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="/secret">Secret</a></li>
    <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li></ul>
```

I got this error:

> Error: Failed to serialize user into session
>       at pass (/home/user/job/NodeJS/test-consumer/second/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:281:19)
>       at Authenticator.serializeUser (/home/user/job/NodeJS/test-consumer/second/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:299:5)
>       at SessionManager.logIn (/home/user/job/NodeJS/test-consumer/second/node_modules/passport/lib/sessionmanager.js:14:8)
>       at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (/home/user/job/NodeJS/test-consumer/second/node_modules/passport/lib/http/request.js:50:33)
>       at OAuth2Strategy.strategy.success (/home/user/job/NodeJS/test-consumer/second/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:248:13)
>       at verified (/home/user/job/NodeJS/test-consumer/second/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:177:20)
>       at OAuth2Strategy.passport.use.OAuth2Strategy [as _verify] (/home/user/job/NodeJS/test-consumer/second/app.js:31:5)
>       at /home/user/job/NodeJS/test-consumer/second/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:193:24
>       at OAuth2Strategy.userProfile (/home/user/job/NodeJS/test-consumer/second/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:275:10)
>       at loadIt (/home/user/job/NodeJS/test-consumer/second/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:345:17)

Every help is welcome.

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add serializer:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});
```

I'm using this module now, but the profile always returns empty.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to override the userProfile

This is the source code

```
const passport = require('passport')
// const { Strategy: GoogleStrategy } = require('passport-google-oauth20')
const { Strategy: GithubStrategy } = require('passport-github')
const { Strategy: OAuth2Strategy } = require('passport-oauth2')
const { GITHUB_CONFIG, OAUTH2_CONFIG} = require('../config')
const Profile = require('./profile')

module.exports = () => {
    // Allow passport to serialize and deserialize users into sessions
    passport.serializeUser((user, cb) => cb(null, user))
    passport.deserializeUser((obj, cb) => cb(null, obj))

    // The callback that is invoked when an OAuth provider sends back user
    // information. Normally, you would save the user to the database
    // in this callback and it would be customized for each provider
    const callback = (accessToken, refreshToken, params, profile, cb) => {
        console.log('access-token',accessToken)
        console.log('refresh-token',refreshToken)
        console.log('profile',profile)
        console.log('params',params)
        return cb(null, profile)
    }

    // Adding each OAuth provider's startegy to passport
    // passport.use(new GoogleStrategy(GOOGLE_CONFIG, callback))
    passport.use(new GithubStrategy(GITHUB_CONFIG, callback))
    const DjangoStrategy = new OAuth2Strategy(OAUTH2_CONFIG, callback)
    DjangoStrategy.userProfile = function(accessToken, done) {
        var self = this;
        this._userProfileURL = 'http://localhost:8001/accounts/profile/';
        this._oauth2.get(this._userProfileURL, accessToken, function (err, body, res) {
            var json;

            if (err) {
            if (err.data) {
                try {
                json = JSON.parse(err.data);
                } catch (_) {}
            }

            if (json && json.message) {
                return done(new APIError(json.message));
            }
            return done(new InternalOAuthError('Failed to fetch user profile', err));
            }

            try {
            json = JSON.parse(body);
            } catch (ex) {
            return done(new Error('Failed to parse user profile'));
            }

            console.log('json', json)

            var profile = Profile.parse(json);
            profile.provider  = 'oauth2';
            profile._raw = body;
            profile._json = json;
            done(null, profile);
        });
        }
    passport.use(DjangoStrategy)
}
```

Create a profile

```
profile.js

exports.parse = function(json) {
    if ('string' == typeof json) {
      json = JSON.parse(json);
    }

    var profile = {};
    profile.id = String(json.id);
    profile.displayName = json.name;
    profile.username = json.username;
    profile.email = json.email;

    return profile;
  };
```

You can also check clone my source code

https://github.com/faisallarai/nodejs-oauth-server.git